# "unknown method" when calling $client->profile->get_info() method Perl's WWW::Facebook::API

Tags: perl, facebook

I am trying to get my profile information using my web app via Facebook's PERL API. (WWW:Facebook:API).

```
    my $sesh = param('sesh');
    my $exp = param('exp');


    print "Your sesh is $sesh <br>";
    my $client = WWW::Facebook::API->new(
            desktop => 0,
            api_key => $api_key,
            secret => $secret,
            session_uid => $uid,
            session_expires => $exp,
            session_key => $sesh
    );









    my %out = $client->profile->get_info( uid => $uid);
```

---

This produces the error:
Error during REST profile.getInfo call:

"...{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method",...."

Am passing everything that is needed to the constuctor and am I calling the method correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bug in the rest API and not a problem with your code (that seems fine to me), if you try to make the same call directly from the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/profile.getInfo/ you'll get the same error. You can even try in your browser
`https://api.facebook.com/method/profile.getInfo?uid=<USERID>&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&format=json`
and this is the answer

```
{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"profile.getInfo"},{"key":"uid","value":"<USERID>"},{"key":"access_token","value":"<ACCESS_TOKEN"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

Thanks.